# How to Fill Multiline Textbox with Datatable Values?

Tags: c#, datatable, textbox

I Have a multiline `TextBox`. I want to fill this  `TextBox` with `DataTable` values, each value separated by "comma"`,` and every line ends with semicolon`;`.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: i dont have any idea how to start it...pls give show me some example

Comment: `.Text = "1,1";`, Winforms, wpf, asp.net? What have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In winforms this should work as desired, you need to add `using System.Linq;`:

```
textBox.Lines = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => String.Join(",", row.ItemArray) + ";")
    .ToArray();
```

If you don't want or aren't able to use the [`Lines` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `TextBox`(f.e. if it's not winforms), you can use this code:

```
var lines = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => String.Join(",", row.ItemArray) + ";");
textBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

This works because `String.Join(",", row.ItemArray)` concatenates all fields with comma.

Comment: Tim Schmelter:it shows:System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.String]

Comment: @Raamraj: that's not true, you haven't used the code. I'm assigning a `String[]` to the [`Lines` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of TextBox. Are you using winforms at all?

Comment: i  used like textBox.Text= table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => String.Join(",", row.ItemArray) + ";")
    .ToArray();

Comment: Thanks  Tim Schmelter....is there any way to display val1,val2,val3; in next line val4,val5,val5;

Comment: @Raamraj: i don't understand that requirement. My answer already shows the real data, it doesn't repeat values (if that is what you are afraid of). Or do you want to append the field-number in every field?

Comment: your answer is perfect...but what iam asking is your answer will display like each line have one value;but iam asking is is there any way two display morethan two values to display in each line

Comment: @Raamraj: my answer already shows every field of each row. So it doesn't matter if the row contains one field or hundred(look at the `ItemArray` which are the fields).